# Внешний ключ к названиям колонок таблицы

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть парочка таблиц

People

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[People] (
    [Id]               INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Surname]          NVARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
    [Name]             NVARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
    [Patronymic]       NVARCHAR (50)  NULL,
    [Login]            NVARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
    [CreationDateTime] DATETIME       CONSTRAINT [DF_People_CreationDateTime] DEFAULT (getdate()) NOT NULL,
    [Password]         NVARCHAR (128) NOT NULL,
    [Active]           BIT            NOT NULL,
    [GraduationYear]   DATE           NULL,
    [Photo]            IMAGE          NULL,
    [DateOfBirth]      DATE           NULL,
    [Email]            NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [PhoneNumber]      NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [Adress]           NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_People_Id] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [DF_People_Login_UNIQUE] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([Login] ASC)
);
```

И Menu_PeopleInfo

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Menu_PeopleInfo] (
    [InfoName]            NVARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
    [ColumnInPeopleTable] NVARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
    [Editable]            BIT            NOT NULL,
    [Regex]               NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [ErrorMessage]        NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Menu_PeopleInfo_ColumnInPeopleTable] 
    FOREIGN KEY ([ColumnInPeopleTable]) 
    REFERENCES ?!?!?!?!?!?!?!?!?!?!?!
);
```

Не получается сделать внешний ключ из таблицы Menu_PeopleInfo по столбцу ColumnInPeopleTable в таблицу People. По сути мне нужно вводить в ColumnInPeopleTable названия колонок в таблице People.

У меня получилось получить список колонок двумя способами

```
SELECT * FROM syscolumns 
 JOIN sysobjects ON syscolumns.id = sysobjects.id
WHERE sysobjects.Name = 'PEOPLE'
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И так

```
sp_columns 'people'
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но вот никак не могу вставить данные о всех возможных названиях колонок во внешний ключ.

Я надеюсь, я доступно описал проблему... Но если всё же нет, то на всякий случай ещё раз опишу: В таблице Menu_PeopleInfo есть колонка ColumnInPeopleTable, нужно сделать так, чтобы я туда мог вводить ни что иное, как названия колонок в таблице People. Просто названия колонок.

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Внешний ключ может ссылаться только на первичный ключ другой таблицы. В SQL нет механизма для работы с хранимыми названиями колонок. Так что контроль вы можете сделать только на уровне триггера, который будет проверять наличие колонки по системным таблицам. А вставлять данные можно и не имея ключа и не имея даже контроля на уровне триггеров.

Comment: Ах да, ключи... Не подумал... Спасибо!